# How does Browser (and some other apps) intercept the Back key before my IME?

Tags: android, android-input-method

I've written an IME that displays some popup windows and closes them when the user clicks Back. It works 99% of the time but some apps (like Browser) are able to intercept the `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK` before my IME, leaving my popup window stuck open.

According to the docs InputMethodService should receive key events before Activity. I've tested this with an Activity and it works as expected.

I checked the Browser source code and it simply overrides `Activity.onKeyDown()` and `onKeyUp()`, which should receive events **after** `InputMethodService.onKeyDown()` and `onKeyUp()`.

Why does the browser seem to receive key events in the wrong order? Please help because I don't want to have to add ugly close buttons to all my popups!!!

Thanks in advance,

Barry

Comment: What browser are you seeing this in? The stock AOSP browser or another? In the general case there is the `onKeyPreIme` method that will receive events for things like the back key before the IME does.

Comment: The stock browser, and Google Search. I've already checked the browser source code (com.android.browser) and onKeyPreIme() is not defined anywhere. :(

Answer (score 1):

Its [Activity.onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29). Be careful when you override the functionality of this button as it can create a very negative user experience if you're doing something unexpected or completely ignoring the back button.

If you're using AlertDialogs or similar for popups you may not need to override the functionality, just setCancelable(true). Touching the screen and the back button will close the dialog.

Comment: He’s talking about input methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dan but that's not it. As Guillaume pointed out I've written an IME not an Activity. A small minority of apps (such as Browser) are intercepting the back key before my IME, which goes against the docs. Also, com.android.browser.BrowserActivity does not implement onBackPressed(), so that can't be it. Plus I tested your answer with an Activity and InputMethodService.onKeyDown() was called before Activity.onBackPressed(), as expected. Why is the Browser different from most other apps?